# Utterly and completely baffled by a Leaflet.js issue with custom maps

Tags: maps, leaflet

I am utterly baffled by what should be a trivially simple thing: displaying a custom (non-Geo) map which is 700 pixels high and 1162 pixels wide.  I have successfully tiled this map using `gdal2tiles.py -p raster -z 0-5` to produce a correctly-named subdirectory of 256x256-pixel files. The `tilemapresource.xml` file confirms these dimensions. (The Y-coordinate ranges from `-700` to `0`, X from `0` to `1162.`)

I calculate:

```
`this.maxBounds = new L.LatLngBounds(L.CRS.Simple.pointToLatLng(southWestPoint,
 this.maxZoom),

L.CRS.Simple.pointToLatLng(northEastPoint,
this.maxZoom));`
```

where `southWestPoint` is `(0, -700)` and `northEastPoint` is `(1162, 0)`.  In LatLng, this corresponds to `(0,0)` and `(21.8, 36.3)`, all of which once again seems quite normal.  (I can, indeed, feed these into the inverse-function `latLngToPoint` and get the original point back...)

I now construct the `TileLayer`, with these options:

```
`{minZoom: 0, maxZoom: 5, tileSize: 256, detectRetina: true, 
 continuousWorld: true, tms : true, noWrap: true, bounds: *(as above)*`
```

... and in a similar fashion, I then construct the `Map`:

```
`var mapOptions = { crs : L.CRS.Simple, 
center :    this.tileLayer.centerLatLng, 
maxBounds : *(the TileLayer's "bounds")* 
zoom : 2, 
minZoom : 0, 
maxZoom : 5, 
layers : [*the tile-layer*]};`
        `
```

... and what I get is ... crazy.  A small box in the center of the screen, which does zoom in and out, never displaying the whole map (no doubt because of tileLayer "bounds") unless you zoom all the way out.  The display never fills the entire area of the window.

I have found that if you *manually* fiddle with the numbers for `bounds` and `maxBounds`, you can in fact coax the entire map to be displayed as it should be.  But of course, I need to be able to *calculate* this.

I **must** be doing something fundamentally-wrong here.  But I cannot see what it is, and so I am desperately (at this point) calling for help.

Comment: Any chance of this being placed onto a demo site?

Comment: I could send you files and a script . . .  The display that I see consists of a tile from the lower third of the map, in a box positioned roughly in the center of the div.  As you zoom out, the display changes but it obviously is never complete.  (But if you turn off "bounds" at the TileLayer, it IS complete, but still in the wrong place.)  Obviously, the root cause of the problem must be:  *something* having to do with Coordinates.

Comment: For instance:  if I *force* a "bounds" (and "maxBounds") that is in the range `(0,0)` to `(75, 58)`, then I will see the intended map, more-or-less correctly positioned.  But, "I made those numbers up."  I find that if I "fiddle with the numbers," I can gradually force(!) the display to be properly positioned and to be of the proper size.  No other factor ... center, etc. ... has any effect.  Only "unexplainable, not-computationally producible" numbers" do it, which of course "is no solution at all."  Leaflet 0.7.3.

Comment: I have posted a live copy of the problematic script at:  http://fp.sundialservices.com/WTF/mapdemo.html The offending script itself is at http://fp.sundialservices.com/WTF/scripts/MapDisplay.js  These files will remain at this location only until the problem is solved.  If you zoom completely out, you'll see an inkling of what the total map display should look like.  But what you initially see is only the bottom-left corner, displayed about the middle of the page, and which you can't move because of "maxBounds."  You don't see all of it because of "tileLayer.bounds."

Comment: What you *should* be seeing is the complete map, initially at zoom-level 2, positioned of course in the proper place in the window, and with all of the map's tiles (but none others) displayed.  I have reduced the problem to a certainty that "the problem is maxBounds."  If I *manually* plug LatLngBounds in here, I can *make* the display be of the right size and in the right place.  But that, of course, is not the point.

Comment: Have you looked over this tutorial? http://omarriott.com/aux/leaflet-js-non-geographical-imagery/ I think you are calculating maxBounds wrong.

Comment: Indeed I have.  I also found a *working* example that does exactly what I want at http://rockcrushercanyon.com/about-the-park/park-map/ ... and which is referenced in a Leaflet issue-report at github (which is how I found it).  (In this example, tiles count down-and-right from the upper left corner.  Mine count up-and-right from the lower left corner.  The bounds-calculations in that tutorial seem very strange to me, "(0,6145) (1024,0)" because Latitude is north/south, Longitude is east/west, but it says "1024 is width, 6145 is height." Maybe I've stared at this too long.

Comment: New info:  I stumbled-upon some code at https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2776 which, with a little whacking, allowed me to overlay the grid with Z/X/Y coordinate numbers.  I can now see that the map orients on (Z/X/Y) "0/0/0," but the image is above that, with "Y" coordinates that grow upward:  -1, -2 ...  The only row that reliably appears is "Y=-1," although the URL requested has "Y=0."  I see lots of 404's for *Y* coordinates as small as "-6," although "X" is never less than "-1."  I'm currently using boundaries equal to X and Y pixel-sizes.  *"Whatever's wrong, it's "Y."* `tms: 1`

Comment: If I turn CRSes and maxBounds and bounds *completely off,* the entire image appears, with (X,Y)=(0,7) at the lower left hand corner, *in*creasing in the X axis but *de*creasing along Y.  The upper-right tile is (X,Y)=(4,5).  Obviously, these coordinates are nonsense.